# Can I access to Nifi Rest-API using localhost instead of actual node-ip address in Nifi cluster?

Tags: apache-nifi

For example; I have 3 nifi nodes in nifi cluster. Example hostnames of these nodes;

1. 192.168.12.50:8080(primary)
2. 192.168.54.60:8080
3. 192.168.95.70:8080

I know that I can access to nifi-rest api from all nifi nodes. I have GetHTTP processor for get cluster summary from rest-api, and this processor runs on only pimary node. I did set "URL" property of this processor to ***192.168.12.50:8080/nifi-api/controller/cluster***.

But, if primary node is down, new primary node will be elected. Thus, I will not be able to access 192.168.12.50:8080 address from new primary node. Because this node was down. So, I will not be able to get cluster summary result from rest-api.

In this case, Can I use ***"localhost:8080/nifi-api/controller/cluster"*** instead of ***"192.168.12.50:8080/nifi-api/controller/cluster"*** for each node in nifi cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a few things... if you are running securely then you have certificates that are generated for each node specific to the hostname, so the host in the web requests needs to match the host in the certificates, so you can't use localhost in that case.

It also depends how NiFi's web server is configured. If nifi.web.http.host or nifi.web.https.host has a specific hostname specified, then the web server is only bound to that hostname and may not accept connections with a different hostname. In a default unsecure setup, if you leave nifi.web.http.host blank then it binds to all interfaces.

You may be able to use the expression language function to obtain the hostname of the current node. So you could make the url something like "http://${hostname()}/nifi-api/controller/cluster".

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response!

For secure nifi cluster; can the flow be like this?
1- ExecuteProcess: Get token for current node using hostname()
2- ExecuteProcess: Receive token from 1, then get data from rest-api using token

Right?

Comment: Yes should be possible, you also might be able to avoid needing a token if you just use the keystore.jsk from the server, so your http processor would use an SSLContextService configured with the same keystore.jks and truststore.jks that is used nifi.properties

Comment: I'll do more research for your second suggestion. Now everything is clearer! Thank you so much!